# Correct way to update notification actions

Tags: android, notifications

I have an app with media buttons and text in the notification that I want to update programatically. So I did this:

```
public void updateNotificatonIcons() {
    ArrayList<NotificationCompat.Action> acts = NotificationBuilder.mActions;
    acts.set(1, new NotificationCompat.Action((isPlaying) ? R.drawable.my_media_stop : R.drawable.my_media_play, "Stop", stopintent));
    NotificationBuilder.mActions = acts;
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(1, NotificationBuilder.build());
}
```

The problem is that AndroidStudio complains about `NotificationBuilder.mActions`:

```
Builder.mActions can only be accessed from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.core with prefix androidx from groupId=Android)
```

I googled and added a `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` before the method, and it works.

Is this the "correct" way of updating the notification? Is there a better way without the need of a `@SupressLint`?

Comment: I did the same thing as you in one of my projects, even though intended way is to use `clearActions` followed by `addAction` for each of your actions I checked source and all those two functions do is alter `mActions` so I've found it mundane to rebuild the arraylist when I was updating one of 3 actions.